# ffmpeg color, size and amplitude

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to get ffmpeg to create an audio waveform while being able to control the image size, color, and amplitude. I have tried this (and many variations) but it just returns unmatched " .

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand=gain=-3,showwavespic=s=1000x350,color=s=1000x350:color=A072FD” -frames:v 1 output.png
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex 
        "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,
         compand=gain=-3,
         showwavespic=s=1000x350:colors=A072FD"
       -frames:v 1 output.png
```

Your closing quote is curly which doesn't match the opening straight quote. Besides that, by putting a `,` after `s=1000x350`, you prematurely terminated the arguments for `showwavespic`.